# GradientBoostingTree training with soft labels in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, training-data

I'm reconstructing a paper. They trained **Gradient Boosting Regression Trees given the input X and soft targets y_s** to get the final output y with minimum mean squared error. Regarding the paper they implemented all decision tree based methods using scitkit-learn package without any modification. This is what I want to do.

If you know the solution already I would be happy to hear, otherwise here are my thoughts:
Just for simplification assume we have a binary problem with 
X = [[x1 x2 x3] [x1 x2 x3]...] and 
y_s [[0.4 0.6][0.8 0.2]...].

Regarding the GradientBoostingTree for classification (see link above), I can only feed in a 1-dim class array

> (y : array-like, shape = [n_samples]) Target values (integers in
>   classification, real numbers in regression) For classification, labels
>   must correspond to classes.

, so even when I would overwrite the cost function (e.g. to cross-entropy) which can handle soft labels, I'm still cannot feed in the 2 dim soft labels (at least).

Another idea was to reduce it to 1-dim by only take one soft label (only works for binary problem where both soft labels add up to 1) and use GradientBoostingRegression instead. But again only one class is possible and I can also not train independent models like

```
X = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
y = [[3.141, 2.718], [3.141, 2.718], [2.718, 3.141]]
rgr = MultiOutputRegressor(GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=0))
rgr.fit(X, y)
X_test = [[1.5,2.5,3.5], [3.5,4.5,5.5]]
rgr.predict(X_test)
```

because of the correlation between the outputs..

Big picture:
1. Extraction of combined features
2.
a) Training: extracted features(Xb), original labels(y) -> logistic regression 
b) Prediction: soft labels (yb)
3. 
a) Training: original features (X), soft labels(yb) -> GradientBoostingTree 
b) Evaluation: predicting normal labels (y_)
-> Importance of original features

The entire procedure without the soft labels is worthless. I mean it has to be possible somehow but I cannot figure out how...

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_regression.html

Answer (score 0):

scikit-learn's docs on [multi-output decision trees](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_tree_regression_multioutput.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-tree-regression-multioutput-py) should point you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm aware about the DecisionTreeRegressor but I don't know how to change it to a GradientBoostingRegressor e.g. to use shrinkage as a regularization method? 
 


GradientBoostingRegressor

Comment: Just to get sure, I changed the estimator and I end with the same error message as before "ValueError: bad input shape" 

So it seems I can use GBR by changing the GradientBoostingRegressor package manually?

Comment: The API for the ['fit' method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.fit) in `sklearn.ensemble` models states that `y` should be shape `[n_samples]`. In contrast, the ['fit' method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.fit) in sklearn.tree allows `y` to have shape `[n_samples, n_outputs]`. I'd expect it to be easier to implement boosting on a `.tree` model than multiple outputs on a `.ensemble' method

Comment: Hmmm, sounds there is no out-of-the-box solution in sklearn which is probably also related to the algorithm. 

Does anyone know an algorithm similar to Gradient Boosting to extract the importance of the features? DT style preferred...

Comment: You can use [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html) sklearn recipe to extract and plot feature importances from decision trees.